# Laravel websocket error :Unhandled promise rejection with TypeError

Tags: laravel, websocket

when i run `php artisan websockets:serve` command, i get below error on my terminal.
i installed pusher and websocket with `composer require pusher/pusher-php-server` and `composer require beyondcode/laravel-websockets` step by step from pusher documentation

my error is:

```
Unhandled promise rejection with TypeError: React\Http\Io\ClientRequestStream::closeError(): Argument #1 ($error) must be of type Excep
tion, Error given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\vendor\react\promise\src\Internal\RejectedPromise.php on line 73 in C:\xampp\htd
ocs\myProject\vendor\react\http\src\Io\ClientRequestStream.php:238
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\vendor\react\promise\src\Internal\RejectedPromise.php(73): React\Http\Io\ClientRequestStream->closeError(O
bject(Error))
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\vendor\react\promise\src\Promise.php(43): React\Promise\Internal\RejectedPromise->then(Object(Closure), Ar
ray)
...
```

Comment: Can confirm this with latest laravel 10 and PHP 8.2.8.

Comment: @VadimPodlevsky reverted to L8/PHP7.4 from L10/PHP8.2 because of Symfony component ^6.0 https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/issues/1146

Comment: prolly https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/issues/1139#issuecomment-1662454787 should resolve the issue. I checked the staging server using this and didn't raise any problem so far (for the last 10 mins).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution that worked for me:**

```
composer require react/promise:^2.3
```

Then

```
composer require pusher/pusher-php-server "~4.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

per Sayed Newaz, it fixes error on my side too

```
"react/promise":"^2.3",
"pusher/pusher-php-server":"~4.0"
```

Comment: ‍‍‍when i run `composer require react/promise:^2.3`i get below error‍‍:`‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍T‍he "2.3" constraint for "react/promise" appears too strict and will likely not match what you want. See https://getcomposer.org/constr aints ./composer.json has been updated Running composer update react/promise Loading composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.    Problem 1 ...` i cant fix my problem yet 
‍‍

Comment: how did you solve this?

Comment: @GuljahanIlmedova i cant solve this

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading the package to 2.7 was enough to get it working for me:

```
composer require react/promise:^2.7
```